# Script variable seems to be getting set to Null

Tags: powershell, diskpart

I am able to run the following commands manually and they work as expected, however when I run this script on the same machine the log file indicates that the $recoveryPartitionNumber is set to Null. I am at a loss as to why this is happening.

NOTE: The code below is only a portion of the script, it is quite long and I wanted to TRY to keep this post concise.

```
    # Gets and stores active recovery partition details
    $reInfo = reagentc /info
    $rePath = $reInfo -match "Windows RE.+partition\d+"
    $recoveryPartitionNumber = $rePath.substring(72,1)
    $recoveryPartition = Get-Partition | Where-Object -Property PartitionNumber -eq $recoveryPartitionNumber

    # Gets and stores primary partition details
    $primaryPartition = Get-Partition | Where-Object DriveLetter -contains "C" | Select-Object
    $primaryPartitionNumber = $primaryPartition.partitionnumber

    Log-Message "Unpartitioned Disk Space: $unallocated" 
    Log-Message "Active Recovery Partition: Partition $recoveryParititonNumber" 
    Log-Message "OS Partition: Partition $primaryPartitionNumber"
    Log-Message ""
    Log-Message "Windows Recovery Envrionment Details: $reInfo" 
}

if ($availableUpdates.kb -match "KB5034441" -and $recoveryParititonNumber -ne $null) 
{
    # The disk has 250MB or more of unpartitioned storage 
    # Just make the recovery partition bigger
    if ($unallocated -ge 262144000)
    {
        Log-Message ""
        Log-Message "There is unpartitioned storage available on disk, increasing recovery parition size." 
        # Disables Windows RE and verifies that it is disabled
        reagentc /disable
        $reInfo = reagentc /info
        if ($reInfo -match "disabled")
        {
            Log-Message ""
            Log-Message "Windows RE disabled"
            $desiredSize = ($recoveryPartition.size + 262144000)
            # Creates a script for diskpart to delete and rebuild the recovery partition
            New-Item -Path "C:\temp\" -Name RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt -ItemType file -Force | Out-Null
            Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt" “select disk 0"
            Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt" “select partition $recoveryPartitionNumber"
            Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt" "delete partition override"
            Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt" "create partition primary id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac size=$desiredSize"
            Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt" "gpt attributes =0x8000000000000001"
            Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt" "format quick fs=ntfs label='Windows RE tools'"

            diskpart /s "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt"
        }

        # Re-enables Windows RE and verifies that it is active, then installs the update
        reagentc /enable
        $reInfo = reagentc /info
        if ($reInfo -match "enabled")
        {
            Log-Message ""
            Log-Message "Windows RE enabled"
            Log-Message "Starting Windows Update"
            Install-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -KBArticleID KB5034441
            if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0){
                Log-Message "Windows Update completed successfully"
            }
            if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 1){
                Log-Message "Windows Update failed, see Windows Update logs for details"
            }
        }
    }

    # The disk does not have at least 250MB of unpartitioned storage, but there is space available on the OS partition
    # Shrink the OS partition then resize the recovery partition
    if ($osDrive.SizeRemaining -ge 8589934592 -and $unallocated -lt 262144000)
    {
        Log-Message ""
        Log-Message "No unpartitioned storage available on disk, but there is free storage on OS partition. " 
        Log-Message "Shrinking OS parition by 250MB and increasing recovery partition size." 
        # Creates a script for diskpart to resize the primary partition
        New-Item -Path "C:\temp\" -Name ResizePrimaryPartition.txt -ItemType file -Force | Out-Null
        Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\ResizePrimaryPartition.txt" "select disk 0"
        Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\ResizePrimaryPartition.txt" "select partition $primaryPartitionNumber"
        Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\ResizePrimaryPartition.txt" "shrink desired=250 minimum=250"

        # Runs diskpart with newly created script
        diskpart /s "C:\temp\ResizePrimaryPartition.txt"

        # Disables Windows RE and verifies that it is disabled
        reagentc /disable
        $reInfo = reagentc /info
        if ($reInfo -match "disabled")
        {
            Log-Message ""
            Log-Message "Windows RE disabled"
            # Creates a script for diskpart to delete and rebuild the recovery partition
            New-Item -Path "C:\temp\" -Name RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt -ItemType file -Force | Out-Null
            Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt" “select disk 0"
            Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt" “select partition $recoveryPartitionNumber"
            Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt" "delete partition override"
            Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt" "create partition primary id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac"
            Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt" "gpt attributes =0x8000000000000001"
            Add-Content –Path "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt" "format quick fs=ntfs label='Windows RE tools'"

            diskpart /s "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt"
        }

        # Re-enables Windows RE and verifies that it is active, then installs the update
        reagentc /enable
        $reInfo = reagentc /info
        if ($reInfo -match "enabled")
        {
            Log-Message ""
            Log-Message "Windows RE enabled"
            Log-Message "Starting Windows Update"
            Install-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -KBArticleID KB5034441
            if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0){
                Log-Message "Windows Update completed successfully"
            }
            if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 1){
                Log-Message "Windows Update failed, see Windows Update logs for details"
            }
        }
    }

    if ($osDrive.SizeRemaining -lt 8589934592 -and $unallocated -lt 262144000)
    {
        Log-Message ""
        Log-Message "ERROR: There is not enough free storage on the disk to safely perform the operation." 
    }

    # Clean up of temp script files
    Remove-Item -Path "C:\temp\RebuildRecoveryPartition.txt" 
    Remove-Item -Path "C:\temp\ResizePrimaryPartition.txt"
}
else 
{
    if ($recoveryParititonNumber -eq $null)
    {
        Log-Message ""
        Log-Message "ERROR: Windows RE is not enabled. Update not applicable."
    }
    else
    {
        Log-Message ""
        Log-Message "Machine does not require this update." 
    }
}
```

I have used this script previously and it has worked on machines before that have only one partition listed by the reagentc /info command, recently I encountered a machine that has two image locations listed by the reagentc command and I am attempting to modify the script to account for such a situation.

Comment: Are you running as admin on the remote machine? The `reagentc /info` cmd requires running as admin

Comment: Yes, I know for a fact that the script is running as admin because the variable $reInfo prints to the log without any error.

Comment: Might be obvious but spit out the value of $reInfo then $rePath first, then since you do a substring on that you will see/debug what is going on....failing that it could be the context it is running in (whoami command) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I feel silly. When I made changes at some point I must have mistyped, when the script checks for the NULL $recoveryPartitionNumber variable, it actually checks the $recoveryParititonNumber variable, WHOOPS!

Comment: Glad to hear you've solved your problem. Please note that one of the standard reasons to close a question is the following: "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo:
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers." As such, please consider deleting your question.